# Select users with only one role

Tags: 7, database

How can i select all users wich have only 1 role. 
For example i got 4 users:

**User 1:**

Role 1,
Role 2

**User 2:**

Role 1

**User 3:**

Role 1,
Role 2

**User 4:**

Role 1

How can i retrieve a list of users wich only got Role 1? But not Role 2.

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
$query->leftJoin('users_roles', 'ur', 'u.uid = ur.uid');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_full_name', 'n', 'u.uid = n.entity_id');
$query->condition(...);
$query->fields('u', array('uid','name','picture'));
$query->fields('n', array('field_full_name_value'));
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll()
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT 
u.uid AS uid,
u.name AS name, 
u.picture AS picture,
n.field_full_name_value AS field_full_name_value,
f.field_function_value AS field_function_value,
pi.field_phone_intern__value AS field_phone_intern__value,
ur.rid AS rid,
COUNT(*) AS rolecount
FROM `dev_drupal_wurth-intranet`.users u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `dev_drupal_wurth-intranet`.users_roles ur ON u.uid = ur.uid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `dev_drupal_wurth-intranet`.field_data_field_full_name n ON u.uid = n.entity_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `dev_drupal_wurth-intranet`.field_data_field_function f ON u.uid = f.entity_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `dev_drupal_wurth-intranet`.field_data_field_phone_intern_ pi ON u.uid = pi.entity_id 
GROUP BY u.uid;
```

This give me the result all the users and their number of roles. Now i tried to filter on this role count with 'WHERE rolecount = 1' but this just gives and sql error.

I'm not very advanced in sql :), still learning.

Thx

Comment: Either use a sub-query count or group the fields - once you've got the actual SQL query worked out, just edit it into the question and we'll help you convert it to Drupal's DB API if you're struggling.

Comment: I added count and group it by uid. But how can filter on rolecount 1? I keep getting sql error :).

Comment: You might review this question for ideas and approaches: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/get-all-users-with-specific-roles-using-entityfieldquery/11186

Comment: Instead of "where rolecount = 1" use "having rolecount = 1" in the original sql. Is your goal to get all users with exactly one specific role or all users with exactly one arbitrary role?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
  $sub_query1 = db_select('users_roles', 'ur')
    ->fields('ur', array('uid'))
    ->condition('ur.rid', '3'); // Role 1

  $sub_query2 = db_select('users_roles', 'ur')
    ->fields('ur', array('uid'))
    ->condition('ur.rid', '4'); // Role 2

  $query = db_select('users', 'u');
  $query->leftJoin('users_roles', 'ur', 'u.uid = ur.uid');
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_full_name', 'n', 'u.uid = n.entity_id');

  $query->condition('ur.uid', $sub_query1, 'IN');
  $query->condition('ur.uid', $sub_query2, 'NOT IN');

  $query->fields('u', array('uid','name','picture'));
  $query->fields('n', array('field_full_name_value'));
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you (and with my poor level), I would proceed in 2 steps:

1. Get all the users with the role that interests you. Maybe inspire yourself for the query here: [Get all users with specific roles using EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/get-all-users-with-specific-roles-using-entityfieldquery)
2. Browse the query result by loading each user and check if `$user->roles` has another role than the one you are looking for.
3. Push the final results in another array.

I don't know if it is a good way to proceed or if there is another way to achieve this, but I think it could do the trick.